# Laravel maatwebsite/excel Corrupted file when download it

Tags: php, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I need create a Excel file and download it, but when I downlaoded the file, the file was currupted.
I searched about this problem and the answer was, 'a space before the php tag', but i cant find, so i save the file in the public folder and there I can open the file, the error just hapen when I download it.

The code:

```
  Excel::create('relatorio_chamados', function($excel) use($result){
      $excel->sheet('Relatorio', function($sheet) use($result) {
          $sheet->with($result);
        });
  })->store('xlsx');
```

Download:

```
public function download($nome){
return response()->download(public_path()."\\uploads\\".$nome);
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This tampering is due to space/ spaces in your code files which corrupt your data passed into excel. you have to debug every corner file by file to identify if there is any space which is not required. It can be at the start of the file i.e. before

If using linux, this command might help to look for right files

```
find . "*" | xargs grep -il \ \<\?php >> php.txt
```